# matplotlib.datesのdates.DateFormatter('%b')が文字化けする

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

以下のpythonスクリプト

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as dates

hours = (( datetime.datetime(2010,8,31,22) - datetime.datetime(2010,7,1,0) ).days + 1) * 24
dates_list = [datetime.datetime(2010,7,1) + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(1,hours)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

#軸の設定
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=5))　#5日間隔に指定
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d%b\n%Y')) #x軸のフォーマットを指定

#plot
aaa = np.ones(len(dates_list))　#適当なデータ
ax1.plot(dates_list,aaa)
plt.show()
```

を実行すると以下の図のようにx軸のDateformatの%bの部分が文字化け(？)しています．英語表記(Jan,Feb,...)に直すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

実行環境はpython3.5 (on anaconda), matplotlibはver.2.1.0になります．

[image: 結果の図]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dates.DateFormatter('%d%b\n%Y')`の`%b`はロケールの月名の短縮形なので、localeが日本語になっていると、`6月`のように`月`がついて表示されます。その場合matplotlib はデフォルトでは日本語フォントに対応していないので`□`いわゆる`豆腐`になってしまいます。

英語表記(Jan,Feb,...)にしたい場合は、locale を英語に変更する必要があるので、スクリプトの最初の部分に以下を追加するようにします。ただし、英語の言語パッケージがインストールされている必要があります。

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

また、`FuncFormatter`を使うことでlocale関係なくカスタマイズすることが可能です。今回のケースであれば以下のようなスクリプトを追加すると英語表記にできます。（[公式マニュアル](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=ticker)）

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

MONTH_NAME = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

def dateFormatter(x, pos):
   dt = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(x))
   return '{0:02d} {1}\n{2}'.format(dt.day, MONTH_NAME[dt.month - 1], dt.year)

formatter = FuncFormatter(dateFormatter)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter) #x軸のフォーマットを指定
```

なお、`6月29日`のように日本語で表示させたい場合は、matplotlibの日本語の表示について、Qiita の方に書いたので、そちらを見てください。

https://qiita.com/yniji/items/3fac25c2ffa316990d0c

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。日本語表記ではなく英語表記(1月→Jan)に直すにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')を冒頭に入れて実行してみたのですが，最初の図とまったく同じでした．matplotlibのfigure上では日本語の設定のままになっているようです.

Comment: matplotlibの方にlocaleの設定はないので、localeの設定がうまくできていないためだと思います。そういう場合に対応を回答に追加しました。

Comment: from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatterを追加して，上記の方法でできました．ありがとうございました．

Comment: 日本語版Windowsだと標準では英語の言語パッケージがインストールされていないので、localeで変更したいのであれば先に英語の言語パッケージがインストールする必要があります。